# IOS CNContactStore executeSaveRequest fails with CNErrorDomain Code=500

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore

When attempting to save a contact that has populated Social Profile data the following error is encountered:   This is seen in iOS 9.2

> Domain=CNErrorDomain,Code=500 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={CNKeyPaths=(SocialProfiles),
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1612681f0{Error Domain=ABAddressBookErrorDomain
>   Code=0 "(null)"}}

I am serializing a contact that already exists in a different phone's address book and when I look at the attributes for the Facebook social Profile Inotice that the UserIdentity attribute is `nil` (`null`).

I'm not sure if I am just missing some knowledge on how this works and this is expected behavior, a usage problem or is it a defect?

Comment: How many social profiles are you trying to save? Do they have a valid label and value for the CNLabeledValue object?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The issue was that the default contact account was an exchange account. The socialProfile save is not allowed in this type of container. Solution is to remove the unsupported property and attempt the save again.

Comment: It is! This error appears when the Contacts app is bound to an Exchange account